# Add a spikey hair badge

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

You should add a badge for when a user goes over 9000 rep that references spiky hair.  Perhaps allow them to wear a spiky hair on their avatar for a day or so to celebrate.  That would be good fun.

**EDIT**

It would seem that my idea has not been generally well received, and granted maybe the idea of adding a hat went a bit to far and the over 9000 was a bit to localized.  However, I think adding anything that would encourage someone to participate on the site is a positive. Maybe a far better approach would be to add some sort of badge every 2k rep or something and allow the community to vote on what they should be.  That would have two positives 1) increase participation 2) allow the community to take more ownership in the site.

Further, this is an approach you see all the time in mediums where you earn points for doing things, see achievements on just about any game in existence today.

**EDIT 2**

There are also plenty of other badges that do little/nothing to encourage positive behavior or teach users about the site.

- Popular Question
- Notable Question
- Famous Question
- Tumbleweed

Also as mentioned in comments below, there are badges that reward rep earned

- Epic
- Mortarboard
- Legendary

Comment: What good behavior would this encourage?

Comment: Badges aren't about "fun".  They are for rewarding positive behavior or teaching users about features of the site.  If you want to wear something, wait for the Winter Bash next year.

Comment: And when someone earns the badge, everyone on the site should hear "IT'S OVER 9000!", right?

Comment: only in their head, I know I would.

Comment: Come on guys where's your sense of funny

Comment: @Jhawins This is meta, we hate fun!

Comment: Adding things like this could also encourage ppl to participate more, and certainly there is no harm in that

Comment: A good laugh is good encouragement to come back to the site and help out even more ;)
Also, getting to 9000 rep means you're getting upvotes/accepts, which mean you're helping out the community, which is positive behavior.

But by all means people go ahead and jump on the Meta-Hate-Everything-Suggested-By-Lower-Rep-Users-And-Higher-But-Not-As-Often-For-No-Reason-Band-Wagon.

Comment: I see no edits by yourself to the question. I also don't see you explaining how this is encourages good behavior in comments. And finally, it wasn't me that set the status to declined. Details, I know, but they are important.

Comment: @oded I edited my post, and based on your comment, I am curious, what positive behavior does the tumbleweed badge elicit or how about the [popular,notable,famous] question badge?

Comment: Tumbleweed is indeed an odd-one-out - it is a consolation prize of sorts. The other badges encourage **sharing** questions, so they can be seen.

Answer (score 5):

Spiky hair like this?

[image: Atwood]

No, but seriously, this is a bad idea. Getting over 9000 rep doesn't really encourage any positive behavior, and neither would a pointy haired badge

Comment: Why not have a badge for getting 10 rep? And another for 20 rep? and 30? continue ad infinitum. (This was a response to a deleted comment, not to this answer :/ )

Comment: Getting to 9000 rep means you're getting upvotes/accepts, which mean you're helping out the community, which is positive behavior.

Comment: @Wooble yeah idk what happened. @ Flagger flag it again if you want, I clearly haven't broken any rules whatsoever.
Although you have a point. Maybe the "OVER 9000!" reference isn't as common as I and the OP thought.

Answer (score 4):

No, please.  Badges should require work.  Spiky hair just involves not taking showers for a while.

Comment: I disagree it would take work to get over 9000 rep

Comment: Why would you get a badge for rep, isn't rep in itself a reward?  There are no existing rep badges.

Comment: If I get 9000 rep for this post, I'll change my position (and give up showers for a week).

Answer (score 1):

This would encourage positive behavior. I am for it.
Helping the community has a side affect of earning you rep, getting to 9000 rep means you have clearly gone out of your way to add your own knowledge to the community. In most cases you've spent days of your life on this community to get to that rep level.

To say that isn't positive behavior is like saying a construction worker didn't play a part in the project he was tasked with. It took many, many workers to build the building he worked on, and each one of them did their part. Just as each member of this community does there part.

If I had this much rep, I would be insulted to be told my 9000 rep wasn't an obvious statement to how much positive impact I've had on this community.

Comment: But the rep itself is a reward already for your positive contributions to the site.  This would be the same as getting a badge because you got a different badge.  We don't need to layer rewards.  What's next, a funny hat because you got the spiky hair and the mortarboard badge.  Then wearable deer antlers because you got the funny hat and the epic badge.  The rep and the good feeling for helping people should be the only incentive you need to gain rep.

Comment: Please see badges ["Mortarboard", "Epic", "Legendary"]. These badges reward receiving rep, they layer rewards. The OP suggested a reward of some kind referencing "OVER 9000!" which is clearly not as common of a reference as I thought. He didn't say "It's gotta be a hat." It was a vague suggestion waiting for further discussion, but there has been no actual discussion here. Just contradicting answers like yours and blatantly untrue answers.

Comment: You said above that you wanted to have a discussion, I stated my position as to why I don't like idea.  Your are the one that seems to be getting angry at anyone who disagrees with your position.  And my comment is not an answer.  It is simply a statement of my personal opinion.

Comment: I'm not angry. Everyone always thinks I'm angry.

Comment: @Jhawins in my experience people often confuse anger with passion

Comment: @iamkrillin I'm not passionate about this...

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in adding a badge for passing a reputation level when your usercard and profile page both will show you having hit that mark.

It'd be the same as given out badges for having a custom profile image, or including a digit in your display name. Or getting a silver badge because you have three brown badges.

Badges like Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary are for reputation related events, but events that are not easily seen from a profile. You have to open up the reputation graph and sit there counting the days hit.

And [since 9000 is a mistranslation](http://www.dragonballencyclopedia.com/wiki/It's_over_9000!), they don't issue Hutchison chapters either.

Comment: I hate to beat a dead horse, but if the criteria is "not on the profile page" the same could be said for Scholar, Student, Autobiographer, & supporter.

Comment: Those all contribute to the experience and citizenship of the site. A badge just for having reputation is redundant when it's clear you have that reputation level. It'd be like giving out badges because you posted an answer. With no other qualifications.

Comment: so what about tag editor, informed, or analytical?  Heck informed requires nothing more than visiting a page and scrolling to the bottom. (clearly less effort than asking a question, as that would at least require typing)

Comment: Your request hinges on reasoning why the badge, in isolation of other badges, should even be added. If you want to ask why other badges are included, that is a separate request.

Comment: @iamkrillin you missed the 2nd portion of my original comment... "or teaching users about features of the site".  Many of those badges aren't about "hard work" but to teach users about the features of the site, like how to edit tags, or that the "about" page exists.